# How to set my activity to how many servers my bot is in?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

So I am trying to set a activity for my bot, but it will only give me the error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setActivity')
```

So how do I set that right in the config.json? (it needs to be in the index as well)

Index.js:

```
 client.user.setPresence({
    activities: [{
      name: presenceName,
      type: presenceType,
    }],
    status: presenceStatus,
  });

})

client.user.setActivity(`serving ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`);
```

config.json

```
{
    "prefix": ".",
    "presenceName": "EVERYONE",
    "presenceType": "WATCHING",
    "presenceStatus": "ONLINE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can only call `.setActivity()` after the bot comes online so it will need to be in the `client.on('ready')` callback function and as per your current code, we cannot see if it is in the `.ready` function so we can assume that it is. After that, when calling `.setActivity()`, you also need to mention whether the bot is either `STREAMING`, `PLAYING`, `LISTENING` or `WATCHING`. So the correct usage for this command would be:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is online!')
    client.user.setActivity('demo', { type: 'WATCHING' })
})
```

You can learn more about `.setActivity()` here => [discord.js | ClientUser](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity)